# Terraform: Object List Value Has No Attributes

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Getting an error on Terraform Plan saying my object has no attributes for the name value. We are deploying about 7 private dns zones and many of them live in the same resource group. some may live in others, but most live in the same one.

```
Error: Unsupported attribute
on Modules/privatednszone/main.tf line 4, in data "azurerm_resource_group" "this":
  name     = each.value.name
This value does not have any attributes.
```

**MAIN**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "2.83.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

variable "private_dns_zones" {
  type = map(object({
    dns_zone_name       = string
    resource_group_name = string
    tags                = map(string)
    vnet_links = list(object({
      zone_to_vnet_link_name    = string
      vnet_name                 = string
      networking_resource_group = string
      zone_to_vnet_link_exists  = bool
      vnet_link_rg_name         = string
    }))
    zone_exists          = bool
    registration_enabled = bool
  }))
  description = "Map containing Private DNS Zone Objects"
  default     = {}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "this" {
  # read from local variable, index is resource_group_name
  for_each = local.rgs_map
  name     = each.value.name
}

locals {
  rgs_map = {
    for n in var.private_dns_zones :
    n.resource_group_name => {
      name = n.resource_group_name
    }
  }
}

output "rgs_map" {
  value = local.rgs_map
}

output "rg_data" {
  value = data.azurerm_resource_group.this
}
```

**TFVARS**
Code below is a sample of two dns zones, but there are additional ones.

```
private_dns_zones = {
  zone1 = {
    dns_zone_name       = "privatelink.vaultcore.azure.net"
    resource_group_name = "Terraform1"
    tags = {
      iac    = "Terraform"
      syntax = "zone1"
    }
    zone_exists = false
    vnet_links = [
      {
        zone_to_vnet_link_name    = "vaultcore-vnet-eastus2-01"
        vnet_name                 = "vnet-eastus2-01"
        networking_resource_group = "Terraform1"
        zone_to_vnet_link_exists  = false
        vnet_link_rg_name         = "Terraform1"
      }
    ]
    registration_enabled = false
  },
  zone2 = {
    dns_zone_name       = "privatelink.monitor.azure.com"
    resource_group_name = "Terraform1"
    tags = {
      iac    = "Terraform"
      syntax = "zone2"
    }
    zone_exists = false
    vnet_links = [
      {
        zone_to_vnet_link_name    = "monitor-vnet-eastus2-01"
        vnet_name                 = "vnet-eastus2-01"
        networking_resource_group = "Terraform1"
        zone_to_vnet_link_exists  = false
        vnet_link_rg_name         = "Terraform1"
      }
    ]
    registration_enabled = false
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you providing an input value for that variable, because the default is an empty Map, and that would result in your error?

Comment: We have a tfvars file that has about 7 private dns zones listed. I misstated my original problem though. It is not a list, but a map of objects.

Comment: What is the actual value of ` var.private_dns_zones`?

Comment: Hello @Vegas588, Can you please add the tfvars file to the question as well

Comment: Hi @AnsumanBal-MT I have added the tfvars file with two examples of private dns zones. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Hi @Marcin - I have added the tfvars for your reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code seems to work fine only if I use different resource group names. As you are using duplicate values of resource group names which is your requirement creating a map `"rgs_map"` with your code is not possible as it will error out with below :

[image]

***So , in order to resolve the above error , I used something like below :***

```
locals {
  rgs_map = {
    for i,n in var.private_dns_zones : "${i}" =>{
      name = n.resource_group_name
    }
  }
}
```

**Complete code:**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "2.83.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

variable "private_dns_zones" {
  type = map(object({
    dns_zone_name       = string
    resource_group_name = string
    tags                = map(string)
    vnet_links = list(object({
      zone_to_vnet_link_name    = string
      vnet_name                 = string
      networking_resource_group = string
      zone_to_vnet_link_exists  = bool
      vnet_link_rg_name         = string
    }))
    zone_exists          = bool
    registration_enabled = bool
  }))
  description = "Map containing Private DNS Zone Objects"
  default = {}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "this" {
  # read from local variable, index is resource_group_name
  for_each = local.rgs_map
  name     = each.value.name
}

locals {
  rgs_map = {
    for i,n in var.private_dns_zones : "${i}" =>{
      name = n.resource_group_name
    }
  }
}

output "rgs_map" {
  value = local.rgs_map
}

output "rg_data" {
  value = data.azurerm_resource_group.this
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I get it now. Since the map uses an index, you have to use that to differentiate the different RGs. Makes sense.

Comment: I am still getting an error. Modules/privatednszone/main.tf line 4. each.value is object with 6 attributes. This object does not have an attribute named "name".

Comment: Please check the for loop in local as you are referring to an attribute named "name" which is not present.. you can just copy paste the data and local block in my answer to your code

Comment: Turns out I had all kinds of typos in there. It is fully working now. Thanks.